# Convert int(round(time.time())) to C#

Tags: c#, python

I am trying to convert this python instruction to C#

```
int(round(time.time()))
```

But I cannot figure out what it does exactly.

Comment: `time.time`, `round` and `int`  are all documented methods in Python. I suggest you have a look at the Python documentation and figure out what each method does. Then try to find equivalent methods in the .NET framework. If you then still have a problem, describe what you've  tried and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: In python console, `help(time.time)` or `help(round)` would have helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use UtcNow as opposed to Now or else you will get an answer offset by your timezone.

```
TimeSpan t = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
int timestamp  = (int) t.TotalSeconds;
```

Answer (score 4):

`time.time()` will return the current time as a float which represents seconds since 1/1/1970, `round()` will round that float to the nearest integer value, and `int()` will convert the value to the integer type.

For example:

```
>>> time.time()
1351702579.645324
>>> round(time.time())
1351702580.0
>>> int(round(time.time()))
1351702580
```