# Converting Python code to a VB.Net function

Tags: python, vb.net

I have the following Python code that I need to convert to VB.Net

```
import time
import http.client
import json


def obfuscate_api_key():
seed = 'myActualKey'
time_now = int(time.time() * 1000)
n = str(time_now)[-6:]
r = str(int(n) >> 1).zfill(6)
obf_key = ""
for i in range(0, len(str(n)), 1):
    obf_key += seed[int(str(n)[i])]
for j in range(0, len(str(r)), 1):
    obf_key += seed[int(str(r)[j]) + 2]

return time_now, obf_key
```

I used an on-line converter from this site https://hwiegman.home.xs4all.nl/python2vb.html#google_vignette

The result:

```
Public Sub obfuscate_api_key()

Dim seed As String
seed = "myActualKey"
Dim time_now As Integer
time_now = int(time.time() * 1000)
Dim n As Integer
n = Mid(str2(time_now), -6 + 1, Len(str(time_now)) - (-6))
Dim r As Integer
r = str2(int(n) >> 1).zfill(6)
Dim obf_key As String
obf_key = ""
for i = 0 To 0 - 1 
    obf_key += seed{int(n{i})}
Next
for j = 0 To 0 - 1 
    obf_key += seed{int(r{j}) + 2}

Next

   '     Return time_now, obf_key
End Sub
```

Plenty of errors, conversion did not work correctly.

Please advise

Regards.

Comment: The braces `{` and `}` are wrong.  Those should be parens `(` and `)`.  If that's what came out of the converter, I'd question the quality.

Comment: Beyond that, please provide more details on what errors you're getting, what you've tried to resolve them, and the specific issues you don't understand.

Comment: Error 1: "zfill is not a member of String" . I changed the curly quotes to round quotes and I can see this error Error 2: "Structure Integer cannot be indexed because it has no default property"

Comment: I suspect convertor is very buggy... Unfortunately I don't know Python and that's why I tried to find some on-line tool

Comment: @user8721 You would be better off looking up what each part of the Python code does and translating it to VB.NET yourself. Trying to start from that "conversion" would be more work than starting from nothing ;) A bit of searching will lead you to useful things like [Convert int(round(time.time())) to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13162986/1115360). Also, consider what it returns.

Comment: zfill I think is a python method that Pads a string.  You might find these functions helpful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padright?view=net-6.0  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=net-6.0